# Business layer implementations

Tags: .net, design-patterns, logic, csla

During my recent curious and often frustrating excursions into the field of Business layer development, I have found many a discussion comparing apples(CSLA.NET) with oranges(Nhibernate) but very few that actually compare the current state of affairs in .NET Business logic development technologies (Rules implementation, Logic validation, Data Transformation, Data Consistency)

It is my wish to compile a list of technologies (frameworks, patterns) that are commonly used to Implement a Business layer.
The target is primarily E-commerce websites that run under .NET

(We can start a new discussion on Java - suggest we stick with one technology first to avoid any confusions)

The idea is for me and my fellow stack exchangers to get visibility on what are the different tools, frameworks, patterns out there to implement a Business layer and not waste their time getting lost in the world of ORM and other data access patterns.

Suggest we use the following template to keep the matter consistent
1. Framework / Pattern Name:
2. Pro's:
3. Con's:
4. When should we use this:

Suggestions are welcomed.

Cheers,
Sam

Comment: This seems too open ended to have a definitive answer.   Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

I've often referred people to some previous posts when discussions of business layer frameworks and domain driven vs data-centric design come up.

http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/p/3465/17247.aspx#17247

and

http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/t/10243.aspx

are both pretty good.